# Symfony4 / Doctrine2 / FOSRestBundle - Inserting / Updating entities

Tags: php, rest, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, symfony4

It's my first time here so I hope so don't be to hard on me.
I'm trying to develop an API Rest on Symfony4 with FosRestBundle, Doctrine2 and JMSSerializer.

Here's my problem:

I have 3 entities organized such as:

1. client which contains extras and a culture
2. culture
3. extra

My annotations and associations are fine. But now I want to insert a client in my database by simply persist and flush my client object. The JSON I send in my body request looks like something like this:

```
{
  client_name: "something"
  culture: {
    culture_id: x
  }
  extras: [
    {
      extra_name: "name1"
    },
    {
      extra_name: "name2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now what I'd like here is simple : creating a client and its extras but not its culture which I know the ID. But if I persist and flush my client entity, culture will be treated the same way. And of course I have other information in my culture entity that I don't want to update.

- Am I missing an annotation to avoid this and just take the ID culture without its content? Is there an annotation that I don't know of and that could solve this?
- Should I get the culture from the database and set it to the client first (I'd like to avoid this to save some automatisms I set up)?

Hope you'll have some ideas guys!

Comment: Are you using forms ? If so can you add the code.

Comment: Hi ! No it's an API context. That's why I'm using FOSRestBundle.

Comment: So you decode manually your JSON and create your entity in your controller ? Can you add a bit of code, or even just logic, so I can adapt my answer.

And you can use form to handle deserialization in your controller, you can take a look at this : https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/form-post ;)